# Static ip route with openvpn

Tags: networking, vpn, routing, openvpn

I have openvpn access server on oracle cloud, and local client on my win 7 pc. I want to create a static route so all internet traffic only flows through the VPN, and nothing else. Ive been able to do this with softether and a third-party VPN service, but I cant get it to work with OpenVPN.

Id delete the 0.0.0.0 route. Then I would make a route in cmd with the destination network my VPN and the gateway my local LAN gateway ie: route add [VPN IP]  mask 255.255.255.255 192.168.1.1. Id connect to my VPN using softether client, which populates a IPV4 address and default gateway for my VPN adaptor, and in turn generates a route for all traffic to flow through this VPN adaptor, the route shows as: 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 [VPN gateway] [VPN interface].

Trying to replicate this procedure, but with openvpn server and open client I am unable to connect. Note: I am able to connect if I reset the routing table, but this defeats the purpose as I want all traffic to only go through the VPN's IP.